# why does the matches() function return false ,when the split() function splits the string correctly to the pattern?

Tags: java, regex

Desired output :
Java
1
8
true
Output produced by this code 
Java
1
8
false
what should be done to return true value ? the pattern of the input is [string] [dot][digit][dot][digit].

```
String st=java 1.8;
String regex="[\\s\\.]";
Pattern p=Pattern.compile(regex);
String []s2=p.split(st);
for(String a:s2)
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(p.matches(st,regex));
```

}
}

Answer (score 1):

You are splitting the string - thus it searches for a *portion* on your string for that regex.

When you use `matches` (which is static and the arguments are in reverse order), you are matching against the *entire* string.

So for example:

```
System.out.println(Pattern.matches(regex, st));
```

where `regex` would change to `".+[\\s\\.].+"` would print `true`.